# How to handle nicely notifications when the main activity is showing?

Tags: android, notifications

I am designing an Android app that does some processing in the background.

The app is designed in such a way that its main activity can show up some events that occured (and sometime prompt the user for input). Now obviously, the main activity is not always showing up and as per the Android guidelines, I'd like to show notifications in this case.

My current implementation uses a message queue class with static methods protected with a mutex: whenever an event occurs, the message is added to the queue and the notification is updated: if the main activity is showing, then the notification is just removed and the messages are popped from the queue. If the main activity is hidden, the notification is created/updated according to the event currently in the queue and the queue is not emptied.

This implementation works so far, but I don't like it. More precisely, the visibility status of the main activity is checked with a static boolean value set to `true` in `onResume()` and to `false` in `onPause()`: this is ugly imho. Also, accessing the static queue from the activity and the background service seems fragile somehow.

Have you already implemented something like that ? What should be the overall design for this ?